# Android maven misses my classes from the jar

Tags: java, android, maven, pom.xml

I'm compiling my Android app using

mvn clean install

When I look into the generated jar my application classes are missing, so my junit tests in another test project will not compile.

Any idea what I need to do to add all my *.class files into the .m2\repository\com\twenty71\jenkinsApp3\1.0.0-SNAPSHOTjar\jenkinsApp3-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?

The mvn built app runs fine, so it's just the jar that's a problem.

This is my pom.xml file:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.twenty71</groupId>
<artifactId>jenkinsApp3</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>jenkinsApp3</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>19.1.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>19.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>19</platform>
                </sdk>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out you folder structure, some time before I also encounter this problem. Maven assumes a /src/main/java/ structure.
First try to create a maven project by command:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.abc.xy. -DartifactId=projectName -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=true.
```

"-DinteractiveMode=true"

by this you may choose your folder structure which maven supports for Android (I never worked with android before so don't have knowledge about its structure)
Then, here Maven will take the folder structure for you, just put your .java file in its /src/main/java/ folder, then build your project again.